# (Average) deviation of a continues random variable

Tags: statistics

I am familiar with the concept of (average) deviation, in case we have a sample of values or the entire population of them, that a quantity, which we are observing, can take.
In case of a discreet variable for the absolute/ unsigned deviation we have:

$D=|x_i-\bar x|$.

Now how would the unsigned deviation look like for the case of a continuous variable?

Comment: Just  the  same..

Comment: how can you compare the expected value with a single value for a continuous variable?

Comment: It is the absolute difference between two real numbers, no problem.

Comment: you don't have a single number when you study continuous variables, you have an expected value within a range and you can have a measured value within a range

Comment: but ofc you cannot subtract ranges of values..

Comment: What ? The expectation is a single number.